# Boolean Enum throws Action can't be blank for false value in Rails-Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, rails-activerecord, rails-admin

I have a rails_admin form (using with rails4 ruby 2.0) with a boolean field : action which symbolises Credit or a Debit action.

I have used enums for the field which works upon selecting the Credit(true) option.
But throws a validation error upon saving '**Action can't be blank**'.

I have the following code in place.

```
field :action, :enum do
  enum do
    [['Credit', true], ['Debit', false]]
  end
end
```

I also tried interchanging the usage of enum by using it as a method.

```
def action_enum
  [['Credit', true], ['Debit', false]]
end
```

but nothing has worked so far.
I tried going though the documentation of rails_admin wiki : https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki but could not work things out.

Can anyone please suggest any solution or point out what it is that i am missing??

Answer (score 7):

For those trying to validate the presence of a `Boolean`, you cannot use `presence: true`.

You need to use:

```rb
inclusion: { in: [ true, false ] }
```

For some crazy reason, this is a thing:

```rb
false.present? #=> true
```

As per https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22962

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

It was the validation :presence => true on the field action which was failing with the false value.
Since `false.present?` always returns false.